# sIFR 3 - does getReplacementByFlashElement() or replaceText() work in IE6?

Tags: javascript, replace, sifr

I'm currently running a Windows XP Pro VM using VirtualBox with IE6 standalone on it for testing purposes.  I have noticed that neither of the text replacement methods appear to be working in IE6, however Safari/FF both handle things fine.  **I would like to know if this issue is pertinent to IE6 in general or am I just suffering from the quirkiness of the standalone version of IE6?**

The two versions of text replacement are as follows (might help some people):

```
sIFR.getReplacementByFlashElement($('#h2-s').children('.sIFR-flash')[0]).replaceText(title);
```

and:

```
replacements['h2.sifr-red'][0].replaceText(title);
```

Comment: Hey Mark, I have tested on native Windows XP SP2 with the default IE6 installation and I don't see a change (using both methods).

Comment: I've tested on IE6 standalone on a Mac and Linux with Flash 10 as well as native Windows XP IE6 with Flash 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it on Internet Explorer 6 SP1 running native on Win2k Pro SP4 and I cannot find any problems.

Comment: Thanks, just needed someone to verify.